# removeColumn does not remove column with foreign key when using migrate:undo with Sequelize CLI

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize CLI for my DB. I needed to add column with foreign key (1:n relation) to an existing table, which went well, column was added succesfully and worked as expected. 
Problem starts, when I run `db:migrate:undo` which is calling `down` function from migration. I am using `removeColumn` there, but it just won't delete the column, just proceed without any errors.

Example of migration:

```
export default  {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.addColumn('table', 'someId', {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'someModel',
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      onDelete: 'set null'
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.removeColumn('table', 'someId')
  }
};
```

The migration itself works fine, just undo is not deleting either column or foreign key, but proceed without any errors. 
Expected behaviour is, that `removeColumn` deletes specified column and  related foreign keys.